AbstractRoutingDataSource multiple data source get from 1 DS and delete/save to another DS
I am doing manual Spring JPA copy from 1 database to another database
@Component
public class DataContextHolder {
    private static final ThreadLocal<DataBaseEnv> contextHolder = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setDataBaseEnv(DataBaseEnv dataBaseEnv) {
        contextHolder.set(dataBaseEnv);
    }

    public static DataBaseEnv getDataBaseEnv() {
        return (DataBaseEnv) contextHolder.get();
    }

    public static void clearDataBaseEnv() {
        contextHolder.remove();
    }
}

public class DataSourceRouting extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return DataContextHolder.getDataBaseEnv();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.datasync", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager", entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JpaDataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSourceRouting actualDataSource(
            @Qualifier("devDataSource") DataSource devDataSource,
            @Qualifier("prodDataSource") DataSource prodDataSource
    ) {
        Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();
        targetDataSources.put(DataBaseEnv.DEV, devDataSource);
        targetDataSources.put(DataBaseEnv.PROD, prodDataSource);

        DataSourceRouting routingDataSource = new DataSourceRouting();
        routingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
        routingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(devDataSource);

        return routingDataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            DataSourceRouting actualDataSource
    ) {
        return builder.dataSource(actualDataSource).packages("com.datasync.model").persistenceUnit("persistenUnitName").build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSourceRouting actualDataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(actualDataSource);
    }
}

Repository: We do not have truncate access, so i need to clear the existing data before copying the source data, so i wrote Delete query.
public interface CountryRegionRepo extends JpaRepository<CountryRegion, Long> {

    @Query("delete from CountryRegion m")
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    void truncate();
}

And then this is my service
    DataContextHolder.setDataBaseEnv(DataBaseEnv.PROD);
    Iterable<EcQriCountryRegion> countryRegions =  countryRegionRepository.findAll();        System.out.println(((Collection<?>) countryRegions).size());
    DataContextHolder.clearDataBaseEnv();
    DataContextHolder.setDataBaseEnv(DataBaseEnv.DEV);
countryRegions =  countryRegionRepository.findAll(); // I am able to get the count from DEV
    countryRegionRepository.truncate();
    System.out.println(((Collection<?>) countryRegions).size());
    countryRegionRepository.saveAllAndFlush(countryRegions);

Here the truncate is giving me

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing
an update/delete query

When it is able to read from the second data source, why it cannot delete or save, what i am missing?

Did not find any fix or solution for this. So i switched from JPA to mybatis following this https://programmer.ink/think/springboot-mybatis-multiple-data-source-switching.html and able to copy from one database to other.
